# URL session initilazition issue

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

```
class URLSessionDataTask: URLSessionDataTask {
    private let url: URL
    private let data: Data

init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration = .default, url: URL, data: Data, statusCode: Int, completion: @escaping ) {
    self.data = data
    self.url = url

}

func execute() {
    let response = HTTPURLResponse(url: url, statusCode: statusCode, httpVersion: nil, headerFields: nil)
    completion(data, response, nil)
}
```

I am working some test it is working but I am getting yellow error, How can i fix my code ?, please help me.

Comment: https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/chapter-8-init-deprecated-in-ios-13/102050/8?u=angrycoder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're receiving this warning because swift automatically calls default `super.init()` which is deprecated. Specify it explicitly:

```
class MockURLSession: URLSession {
    private let url: URL
    private let data: Data
    private let statusCode: Int
    
    init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration = .default, data: Data, statusCode: Int, url: URL = URL(string: "https:flicker.com")!) {
        self.data = data
        self.url = url
        self.statusCode = statusCode
        super.init(configuration: configuration)
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, can you have a look please ? - it doesnt work with completion handler somehow

Comment: @Kariny what do you mean by saying it doesn't work? error, crash? what's `NetworkRouterCompletion`?

Comment: `Argument passed to call that takes no arguments` when i add to super.init(configuration: configuration)

Comment: @Kariny sounds like you're missing some brackets or some accidental typo somewhere, check on other changes because adding a block shouldn't cause such error

Comment: @Kariny this is because you are subclassing `URLSessionDataTask` which doesn't have that initialiser

Answer (score 1):

Subclass initialiser must call the superclass initialiser after initialising all subclass properties.

The warning is produced because of an implicit `super.init()` call added by the compiler. You need to explicitly call one of the non-deprecated initialisers, such as `init(configuration:)`.

```
class MockURLSession: URLSession {
    private let url: URL
    private let data: Data
    private let statusCode: Int

    init(data: Data, statusCode: Int, url: URL = URL(string: "https:flicker.com")!) {
        self.data = data
        self.url = url
        self.statusCode = statusCode
        super.init(configuration: .default)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you have a look my edited question as well please ?